# How to determine the norton- and thevenin equivalent circuit of this circuit?

Tags: analog, thevenin, norton

I was wondering how to determine the Norton- and thevenin equivalent circuit for this circuit using superposition. \$R_1=R_2=R_5=100 \Omega, \ \ R4=470 \Omega \ \ R3=330 \Omega\$ \$V_1=10V, V_2=100V\$.

I have managed to derive \$R_T=62 \Omega \$ by setting both voltage sources to \$0V\$.

Through superposition I tried to determine \$V_{OC}\$ and by setting \$V_2=0\$ I obtained \$V_{OC_{1}}=6.14V\$ but I have no idea how to think when setting \$V_1=0\$? What tricks am I allowed to use? Any tips would be appreciated!

/J
[image: Circuit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using super position treat voltage sources that are set to zero as a short circuit or just a wire. Current sources set to zero are treated as an open or a break in the wire.

Comment: Yes I know, but when setting V1 to zero, I am left with something that I don't know how to simplify.

Comment: @J.Doe If you are looking for straight resistor conversions, look into Y Delta conversions. R1 R2 R3 will form a delta and converting it to a Y will let you do that. You can also use mesh or nodal analysis to solve the circuit without simplifying it.